# Getting "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command" when installing phantomjs through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

I've been working on a large project using NPM to manage my dependencies. In the past I've gotten it to build just fine, however the team made some recent changes that have updated the dependencies and I needed to rebuild to ensure I had everything up to date.

When I run 'npm install' on the main directory, it seems to go fine right up until it tries to install phantomjs@1.9.19, at which point I get the following :

> phantomjs@1.9.19 install c:\Users\me\Perforce\drice_vir_ui\node_modules\phantomjs
>
> node install.js
>
> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "phantomjs"
>
> npm ERR! node v5.0.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.3.7
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.19 install: `node install.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.19 install script 'node install.js'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node install.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

When I run "node -v" I get "v5.0.0" as a response, so I know that node is correctly installed. I've been digging through stackoverflow, github, and anywhere else that has error threads that might help, but nothing has worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Run `curl -L "https://npmjs.org/install.sh" | sh` and then try `npm install` again. See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: That worked. If you submit it as a solution I'll mark it as being correct.

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Run

`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Then once done, rerun `npm install` and everything should be fixed.